# Open Popup using thickbox after 5 sec

Tags: asp.net, popup, thickbox

I am developing web application. In that i want to open one popup using thickbox after 5 seconds when user comes to entry page.

Can any one give some idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `setTimeout()` from javascript with the command from the thickbox, something like:

```
// when dom is ready
$(document).ready(function() {
      // set a timer thats run 5sec
     setTimeout(function(){    
      // open the pop
      var me = $('#ElementToOpen');
      var t = "title"
      var a = "openurl";
      var g = false;
      tb_show(t,a,g);    
    },5000);
});
```